# How do I set traditional printer settings from a Modern UI app (Reader)?

Tags: windows-8, printing, modern-ui

How do I change settings such as print quality and duplexing when printing from a Modern UI app? Or, better yet, access all the traditional settings including greyscale, watermarks, mirroring, scaling, etc. provided by my printer driver?

From Reader (Modern UI):

[[image: ReaderScreenshot]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxMux.png)

From Firefox (Desktop):

[[image: FirefoxScreenshot]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7uRN.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 8 has a [new printer model](https://web.archive.org/web/20151205144913/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/b8/archive/2012/07/25/simplifying-printing-in-windows-8.aspx) that allows printer drivers to add Modern-style UI.

> If the manufacturer hasn't provided any configuration UI for their device, then Windows provides some standard UI that you can use with any printer. However, when the printer manufacturer has decided to invest in providing a customized experience for their device, they can provide an app that replaces the standard Windows UI. Then, when you decide to alter the configuration of the device, or when the device configuration changes during printing (e.g. paper jam), then Windows will display the manufacturer’s customized app to you instead.

You need to wait for your printer manufacturer to release a proper Windows 8 driver that adds these additional options for Modern UI apps.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Unfortunately, it seems HP's Windows 8 drivers don't include such functionality. I have found a viable workaround, however :)

Comment: @Bob: Hopefully, they'll fix that soon.

Comment: I'd like to vote down Microsoft ten times !!!

Answer (score 3):

A workaround is to set the default options via Control Panel => Devices and Printers.

All print jobs should use the default settings, which can be set from the Desktop Control Panel. With testing, this seems to hold true for Modern UI apps.

Right click on the printer and select Printing Preferences. Change settings as desired and save. Try printing from the Modern UI app. Remember, these settings will persist until you change them (back).

Answer (score 0):

Another Workaround is to install *Adobe Acrobat Reader*, and to uninstall Windwos 8 *Reader*. After, you can again freely adjust printer proerties, and even open two pdf's side by side.

Get free from Microsoft mediocrity !