# Viewing printer properties in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, printer, device-manager

I recently upgraded to windows 8 but noticed that there is no longer a Device Manager application, thus no way for me to view the status of my devices. After a couple of minutes of playing around I found a list of all of my installed devices, but nothing that would indicate the status of those devices such as current ink level, amount of paper etc. How can I view these things?

Answer (score 2):

My favorite way to view printers is through the Print Management snap-in.

<sub>(Print Management console is unavailable on Windows 7 Home Premium, and possibly other versions as well. YMMV.)</sub>

Open an MMC using <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open a run dialog and type MMC, add a snap-in by pusing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, and add `Print Management` to the list:

[image]

Now `Add the Local Server` to view the printers on your computer:
[image]

Click `Finish`, `Ok`, and drill down in to the snap-in:
[image]

From here you can conveniently manage printers, drivers, and ports. Right click a printer to open its properties. Use the `More Actions` menu add ports/printers/drivers or open dialog boxes to mange them.

---

You can also add `Device Manager` to the MMC by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and adding `Device Manager`.

[image]

---

As far as ink levels, this might depend on your printer, its drivers, and proprietary software. You may be able to find it hiding in the properties somewhere though.

Comment: Thanks, this answer actually went above and beyond what I was asking.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this device manager?

[image]

Just go to **Computer** > **System properties** (in the ribbon) > **Device Manager** (on the left panel).

[image]

Alternatively, an easier way is to right-click the bottom-left corner (start menu) to access **Device Manager**:

[image]

Exactly what data you get from the printer (ink level/paper) would depend on your printer and its drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked `Control Panel / Devices and Printers` or the `Charms bar / Devices`?

[image]

Also see [How do I set traditional printer settings from a Modern UI app (Reader)?](https://superuser.com/questions/494329/how-do-i-set-traditional-printer-settings-from-a-modern-ui-app-reader)

Answer (score 0):

You can also highlight any single printer in the printer and devices window and the menu bar changes and adds the option for printer server.