# How to print in a Windows 8 Modern UI app using the native printer dialog

Tags: windows-8, printing, modern-ui

The printer dialog of Modern UI is simple, but it is missing advanced features for business range printers. Is there a way to access the native printer dialog from within a Metro (Modern UI) App ?

The use case is in Windows 8 *Reader* for PDF, which cannot be run in desktop mode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set traditional printer settings from a Modern UI app (Reader)?](http://superuser.com/questions/494329/how-do-i-set-traditional-printer-settings-from-a-modern-ui-app-reader)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thanks, i didn't find it.